# TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I searched for the same error of .map is not a function all over. But the solutions provided not worked out for me. In my case, the home screen loads properly initially. But if I redirect to it from another page, the above error occurs.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";

function HomeScreen(props) {
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { products, loading, error } = productList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
    return () => {
      //
    };
  }, []);

  return loading ? (
    <div>Loading....</div>
  ) : error ? (
    <div>{error}</div>
  ) : (
    <ul className="products">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <div className="product">
            <Link to={"/product/" + product._id}>
              <img
                className="product-image"
                src={product.image}
                alt="product"
              />
            </Link>

            <div className="product-name">
              <Link to={"/product/" + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
            <div className="product-price">{product.price}</div>
            <div className="product-rating">
              {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: map can be used only for arrays. Since, you are getting the value from Redux store, check using dev extension if product is in fact an array or some other value.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log('products',JSON.stringify(products,undefined,2))` and see what products is? Normally the first step in debugging a redux app is looking at the redux dev tools and see what actions are dispatched and how the state is chaned/what the state value is. If that is what you already did then could you provide this information in your question?

Comment: the map method is used on array. Either console.log, whether the products being returned is an array or use the redux extension tool, to check as well.

Comment: It looks like you're using an entity pattern to store the products, therefore your state is an object keyed by product id. You can say Object.values(state.productList) to get the products as an array.

Comment: I checked using the redux dev tool. Products are initially sent as an array. but not returned as an array. Is there a way to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

While your redux function is being performed, `products` is undefined,
you theirfore have to wait for data by utilizing your `loading` parameter to render something untill your store updates or u can try to supplie initial empty array and when data is recived, it will update the DOM like : -

```
const { products, loading, error } = productList;
   const theProducts  =  products || []

   theProducts.map((d) => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I found out that in my product list reducer I defined my products as an object instead of an array

```js
export const topProductsReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_TOP_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] };
    case PRODUCT_TOP_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload, success: true };
    case PRODUCT_TOP_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I had to change the products state from and object to an array as above